# How to know key presses in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need to detect every key press on either a soft or hard keyboard in `EditText`. I just need to send the characters one at a time as they are pressed and don't need the final text string.

I have tried using an `EditText` with `onKeyPress`, but I ran into the problems here with not getting key presses with soft keyboards and `TextWatcher` isn't a good option because I need each key press.
Is there any solution to know all the keypresses (including back, shift, enter... also)?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you have an `EditText`, then you can use the `TextWatcher` interface. In my code, `search_edit` is an `EditText`.

```
search_edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {          
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {                                   
        //here is your code
        myadapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        listview.setAdapter(myadapter); 
    }                       
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
    }                       
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
    }
});
```

Comment: Won't it trigger if the text is changed programmatically? Is this really a key press event or just a text changed event?

Comment: That's not an answer.

Answer (score 9):

Implement this:

```
 et_code_1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    /* do something */
                }
            return true;
            }
        });
```

### Update:

As you would like to implement a Soft key listener, you can implement [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html). Here is an example: [How to use the TextWatcher class in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-textwatcher-in-android)

Comment: Works only for hardware keys.

Answer (score 4):

Use `addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher)` and implement TextWatcher interfaace.

Comment: TextWatcher events will be called for editText.setText(...); as well, which I guess is not a good option for the requestor.

Comment: keypress not textchange

Answer (score 0):

You can use setOnKeyListener

Work only hardware keys for ex:- backspace key, enter key etc.

```
binding.edt1.setOnKeyListener { view, i, keyEvent -> 
    true
}
```