# How to use the TextWatcher class in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

Can anyone tell me how to mask the **substring** in `EditText` or how to change `EditText` **substring input to password type** or **replace** by another **character** like this 123xxxxxxxxx3455

```
 String contents = et1.getText().toString();
 et1.setText(contents.replace.substring(0, contents.length()-2),"*");
```

Please, tell me how I can use the `TextWatcher` method in Android.

Answer (score 179):

For use of the `TextWatcher`...

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Comment: what to do with this TextWatcher? Provide more detail for better understanding.

Comment: In the method which are overridden for the text watcher. you can mask the text which you really wanted to.

Comment: but i dont know how to use TextWatcher can u explain with little example thanks for ur guidelines

Comment: put this code in java..as soon as user type the text one of the method will be called...according to the name of the function.

Comment: so you wanted to display like this when user is actually typing the text?

Comment: Actually if this is the requirement then better not to use the text watcher.it's going to infinite loop

Comment: This code is working for me, but have a little issue. i have 6 textviews, when i run the app then it will focus 6th textview why this is happened. I want that my first textview will focus first. Please give me suggestion.

Comment: check something called requestFocus for android UI component

Comment: What can this `TextWatcher` achieve that `OnKey` can't?

Answer (score 162):

The `TextWatcher` interface has 3 callbacks methods which are all called in the following order when a change occurred to the text:

```java
beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
```

- Called **before** the changes have been applied to the text.
  The `s` parameter is **the text before** any change is applied.
  The `start` parameter is the **position** of the beginning of the changed part in the text.
  The `count` parameter is the **length** of the changed part in the `s` sequence since the `start` position.
  And the `after` parameter is the **length of the new sequence** which will replace the part of the `s` sequence from `start` to `start+count`.
  You **must not change** the text in the `TextView` from this method (by using `myTextView.setText(String newText)`).

```java
onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)`
```

- Similar to the `beforeTextChanged` method but called **after** the text changes.
  The `s` parameter is **the text after** changes have been applied.
  The `start` parameter is the same as in the `beforeTextChanged` method.
  The `count` parameter is the `after` parameter in the beforeTextChanged method.
  And the `before` parameter is the `count` parameter in the beforeTextChanged method.
  You **must not change** the text in the `TextView` from this method (by using `myTextView.setText(String newText)`).

```java
afterTextChanged(Editable s)
```

- You **can change** the text in the `TextView` from this method.
  **/!\ Warning:** When you change the text in the `TextView`, the `TextWatcher` will be triggered again, starting an infinite loop. You should then add like a `boolean _ignore` property which prevent the infinite loop.
  Exemple:

```java
new TextWatcher() {
        boolean _ignore = false; // indicates if the change was made by the TextWatcher itself.

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (_ignore)
                return;

            _ignore = true; // prevent infinite loop
            // Change your text here.
            // myTextView.setText(myNewText);
            _ignore = false; // release, so the TextWatcher start to listen again.
        }

        // Other methods...
}
```

### Summary:

[image]

---

### A ready to use class: `TextViewListener`

Personally, I made my custom text listener, which gives me the 4 parts in separate strings, which is, for me, much more intuitive to use.

```
 /**
   * Text view listener which splits the update text event in four parts:
   * <ul>
   *     <li>The text placed <b>before</b> the updated part.</li>
   *     <li>The <b>old</b> text in the updated part.</li>
   *     <li>The <b>new</b> text in the updated part.</li>
   *     <li>The text placed <b>after</b> the updated part.</li>
   * </ul>
   * Created by Jeremy B.
   */
  
  public abstract class TextViewListener implements TextWatcher {
    /**
     * Unchanged sequence which is placed before the updated sequence.
     */
    private String _before;
  
    /**
     * Updated sequence before the update.
     */
    private String _old;
  
    /**
     * Updated sequence after the update.
     */
    private String _new;
  
    /**
     * Unchanged sequence which is placed after the updated sequence.
     */
    private String _after;
  
    /**
     * Indicates when changes are made from within the listener, should be omitted.
     */
    private boolean _ignore = false;
  
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence sequence, int start, int count, int after) {
        _before = sequence.subSequence(0,start).toString();
        _old = sequence.subSequence(start, start+count).toString();
        _after = sequence.subSequence(start+count, sequence.length()).toString();
    }
  
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence sequence, int start, int before, int count) {
        _new = sequence.subSequence(start, start+count).toString();
    }
  
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable sequence) {
        if (_ignore)
            return;
  
        onTextChanged(_before, _old, _new, _after);
    }
  
    /**
     * Triggered method when the text in the text view has changed.
     * <br/>
     * You can apply changes to the text view from this method
     * with the condition to call {@link #startUpdates()} before any update,
     * and to call {@link #endUpdates()} after them.
     *
     * @param before Unchanged part of the text placed before the updated part.
     * @param old Old updated part of the text.
     * @param aNew New updated part of the text?
     * @param after Unchanged part of the text placed after the updated part.
     */
    protected abstract void onTextChanged(String before, String old, String aNew, String after);
  
    /**
     * Call this method when you start to update the text view, so it stops listening to it and then prevent an infinite loop.
     * @see #endUpdates()
     */
    protected void startUpdates(){
        _ignore = true;
    }
  
    /**
     * Call this method when you finished to update the text view in order to restart to listen to it.
     * @see #startUpdates()
     */
    protected void endUpdates(){
        _ignore = false;
    }
  }
```

Example:

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextViewListener() {
        @Override
        protected void onTextChanged(String before, String old, String aNew, String after) {
           // intuitive use of parameters
           String completeOldText = before + old + after;
           String completeNewText = before + aNew + after;
           
           // update TextView
            startUpdates(); // to prevent infinite loop.
            myEditText.setText(myNewText);
            endUpdates();
        }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that the cursor doesn't stay were it is supposed to be or at least that has been my experience.

Comment: Is it textview that calls these methods

Comment: I do suppose so

Comment: fixed problem with cursor this way: protected void onTextChanged(String before, String old, String aNew, String after, Editable sequence)

Answer (score 60):

## Supplemental answer

Here is a visual supplement to the other answers. My fuller answer with the code and explanations is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47263021/3681880).

- Red: text about to be deleted (replaced)
- Green: text that was just added (replacing the old red text)

[image]

Answer (score 11):

For **Kotlin** use **KTX extension** function:
*(It uses `TextWatcher` as previous answers)*

```
yourEditText.doOnTextChanged { text, start, count, after -> 
        // action which will be invoked when the text is changing
    }
```

import `core-KTX`:

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0"
```

Answer (score 6):

A little bigger perspective of the solution:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, container, false);
        View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.et1);
        ((TextView) tv).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                 SpannableString contentText = new SpannableString(((TextView) tv).getText());
                 String contents = Html.toHtml(contentText).toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
```

This works for me, doing it my first time.

Answer (score 6):

**Using TextWatcher in Android**

Here is a sample code. Try using `addTextChangedListener` method of TextView

```
addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        BigDecimal previousValue;
        BigDecimal currentValue;

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int
                count) {
            if (isFirstTimeChange) {
                return;
            }
            if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
                try {
                    currentValue = new BigDecimal(s.toString().replace(".", "").replace(',', '.'));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    currentValue = new BigDecimal(0);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            if (isFirstTimeChange) {
                return;
            }
            if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
                try {
                    previousValue = new BigDecimal(s.toString().replace(".", "").replace(',', '.'));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    previousValue = new BigDecimal(0);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (isFirstTimeChange) {
                isFirstTimeChange = false;
                return;
            }
            if (currentValue != null && previousValue != null) {
                if ((currentValue.compareTo(previousValue) > 0)) {
                    //setBackgroundResource(R.color.devises_overview_color_green);
                    setBackgroundColor(flashOnColor);
                } else if ((currentValue.compareTo(previousValue) < 0)) {
                    //setBackgroundResource(R.color.devises_overview_color_red);

                    setBackgroundColor(flashOffColor);
                } else {
                    //setBackgroundColor(textColor);
                }
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Create custom TextWatcher subclass:

```
public class CustomWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private boolean mWasEdited = false;

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        if (mWasEdited){

            mWasEdited = false;
            return;
        }

        // get entered value (if required)
        String enteredValue  = s.toString();

        String newValue = "new value";

        // don't get trap into infinite loop
        mWasEdited = true;
        // just replace entered value with whatever you want
        s.replace(0, s.length(), newValue);

    }
}
```

Set listener for your EditText:

```
mTargetEditText.addTextChangedListener(new CustomWatcher());
```

Comment: This is actually a clever, lightweight way of solving the problem! thanks!

Comment: Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. Please specify proper '-jvm-target' option

Answer (score 2):

```
    public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText firstEditText;
    EditText secondEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        firstEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstEditText);
        secondEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.secondEditText);

        firstEditText.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextListener());

    }

    private class EditTextListener implements TextWatcher {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            secondEditText.setText(firstEditText.getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you implement with dialog edittext. use like this:. its same with use to other edittext.

```
dialog.getInputEditText().addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (start<2){
                dialog.getActionButton(DialogAction.POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
            }else{
                double size =  Double.parseDouble(charSequence.toString());
                if (size > 0.000001 && size < 0.999999){
                    dialog.getActionButton(DialogAction.POSITIVE).setEnabled(true);
                }else{
                    ToastHelper.show(HistoryActivity.this, "Size must between 0.1 - 0.9");
                    dialog.getActionButton(DialogAction.POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
                }

            }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to implement all methods of the `TextWatcher` to I created an abstract Class `TextObserver` and voila problem solved:

```
package com.mindef.idttpda.shared;

// dependencies
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;

/**
 * text watcher is converted to abstract class because
 * then not all methods have to be overridden.
 */
public abstract class TextObserver implements TextWatcher {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to override/implement all methods of the `TextWatcher` and put `stub` code in methods I don't use so to keep things simple :-) I created an abstract Class `TextObserver` and voila problem solved.

> Don't know why they implemented it anyway as an Interface and not as
> an abstract class because most of the time only one method is used and
> an Interface is a contract that says that all methods must be
> implemented.

```
package com.mindef.idttpda.shared;

// dependencies
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;

/**
 * text watcher is converted to abstract class because
 * then not all methods have to be overridden.
 */
public abstract class TextObserver implements TextWatcher {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
}
```