# EditText to allow unique letters

Tags: android

how to make edittext should get unique letters as input.

if already letter is there in the edittext we should filter it

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check inserted text after each input character.

by implementing  **TextWatcher**

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8543479/1289716) answer

you can write your code in

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
     // your code for checking unique character here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is you register a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to your `EditText` and override `afterTextChanged`.

And store it using [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Answer (score 0):

try using [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to filter chars input by user

```
   TextWatcher mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        private CharSequence temp;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            temp = s;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                   //CHECK HERE FOR UNIQUE LETTERS as INPUT BY USER and REMOVE IT
            }
        }
    };
```