# Android: Howto send requests to the Google API when a user pauses typing?

Tags: android, autocomplete

I am working on this app where users can enter a location in an autoCompleteTextView and it will suggest locations based on the Google Places Api as is described [here](https://developers.google.com/academy/apis/maps/places/autocomplete-android).

However i would like to restrict the amount of request send by the app by only sending requests if the user stops typing for a certain amount of time. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution to the above problem which is working quite nicely. I have extended the AutoCompleteTextView in the following way. If anyone knows how to further improve this code please let me know.

```
public class MyAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

// initialization
int threshold;
int delay = 750;
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable run;

// constructor
public MyAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void performFiltering(final CharSequence text, final int keyCode) {
    // get threshold
    threshold = this.getThreshold();

    // perform filter on null to hide dropdown
    doFiltering(null, keyCode);

    // stop execution of previous handler
    handler.removeCallbacks(run);

    // creation of new runnable and prevent filtering of texts which length
    // does not meet threshold
    run = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (text.length() > threshold) {
                doFiltering(text, keyCode);
            }
        }
    };

    // restart handler
    handler.postDelayed(run, delay);
}

// starts the actual filtering
private void doFiltering(CharSequence text, int keyCode) {
    super.performFiltering(text, keyCode);
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I used this for the Google Place API at https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android

Answer (score 14):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13210410/60606) but slightly more concise and without introducing extra state. You also don't need the threshold checks since `performFiltering` is only called when filtering is actually required.

Subclassing `AutoCompleteTextView` seems to be the only way to go, since you cannot override/replace the `TextWatcher` added by `AutoCompleteTextView`.

```
public class DelayAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {           
    public DelayAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            DelayAutoCompleteTextView.super.performFiltering((CharSequence) msg.obj, msg.arg1);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void performFiltering(CharSequence text, int keyCode) {
        mHandler.removeMessages(0);
        mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(mHandler.obtainMessage(0, keyCode, 0, text), 750);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using an adapter for the AutoCompleteTextView that implements the Filterable interface and has its own performFiltering method. Can I achieve the above functionality using this setup?

Comment: I think you'd lose any characters typed between when the delayed message is scheduled and when the `handleMessage()` gets called, unless the `AutoCompleteTextView` hands you a reference to the internal `CharSequence` and not a copy of the text so far.  Probably safer to have the `handleMessage()` method pull the text from the View when it calls `performFiltering()`

Comment: @ColinM., there is only a split-second delay between the two events. So I guess it's probably okay to filter based on the text captured when the message was scheduled

Answer (score 0):

You could use a TextWatcher, and monitor how long between text entries.  I personally don't like the idea of sub-classing native Android controls (though, it is certainly a valid approach, just not my preferred approach).

The docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

and a SO link:
[How to use the TextWatcher class in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-textwatcher-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answers above, I found I needed to subclass AutoCompleteTextView. However, because internet is a bit slow where I live, I found that removing the delayed handlers every time the user pressed a key was a problem. So basically if I only ran the filter maybe 500ms after the user stopped typing, it might take seconds for the results to appear, which would make the user annoyed.

So instead, I do not clear the handler every time, and let filtering run every couple hundred ms. My code is much less clean Jan Berkel's. I'm sure you can clean it up a bit I'm too lazy, but performance is better in areas with slow internet IMO.

```
public class CustomCompleteView extends AutoCompleteTextView{

Handler handler=new Handler();
Runnable r;
boolean cleartogo=false;
boolean pending =false;
CharSequence btext; 
int bkeyCode;
public CustomCompleteView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomCompleteView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context,attrs);
}
public CustomCompleteView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context,attrs,defStyle);
}

@Override
public void performFiltering(CharSequence text, int keyCode){
    if (cleartogo){
        cleartogo=false;
        Log.d(MainActivity.DTAG,"Going to filter on " + text.toString());
        pending=false;
        super.performFiltering(btext, bkeyCode);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d(MainActivity.DTAG,"Filtering rejected, too soon");
        btext=text;
        bkeyCode=keyCode;
        if (!pending){
        if (r==null)
            r=new MyRunnable(this);
        //try{handler.removeCallbacks(r);} catch (Exception ex){};
        handler.postDelayed(r, 500);
        pending=true;}
    }

}

private class MyRunnable implements Runnable {


CustomCompleteView bc;


    MyRunnable(CustomCompleteView c ) {
        this.bc=c;

    }

    public void run() {
        Log.d(MainActivity.DTAG,"Special Runnable running");
        cleartogo=true;
        bc.performFiltering(btext, bkeyCode);


    }
}

}
```