# android registration form validation

Tags: android, validation, registration

what method should i use to validate a login registration form in android ?

The validation should take place once the user moves on to the next edittext.

Comment: You need provide more details on what you have tried and your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you want to validate values being entered by user in EditText, if this is the case then you can implement **[TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)** for the EditText.

Check this thread: [How to use the TextWatcher class in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-textwatcher-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **setOnFocusChangeListener** of the EditText.

Set your validation code in onFocusChange of setOnFocusChangeListener. Once your focus is off then the code/your validation will execute.

Have a look at the following code.

```
edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() 
{          

                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
                    {
                        if(!hasFocus)
                        {
                            // your validation code
                        }
                    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement .. Do validation when editText loses focus ...

```
edit_Text.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
  if(hasFocus){

  }else
      // Do validation here.....
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There Are 2 Ways to Validate

1. at each Field Validation
2. on `Button` click Validation 
   for Type One you need to Implement `TextWatcher` for each Field 
   sample Snippet is Following

   ```
   EdittextFieldName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
   {                    
   @Override

     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   }
               });
   ```

   and for type 2 You need to check field Data Validations According to filed Type 
   like

   - Email formate is invalid
   - Email not entered
   - empty field
   - not followed Sequence etc