# Search function in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-searchmanager

My array is like {"Samsung Tab","Samsung Note","Samsung Galaxy","Samsung Galaxy Pro","Nokia Lumia","Nokia 5130","Sony Xperia"} some thing like that.i have edit text type **GALAXY** and click the button i have **GO** i want to show only **Samsung Galaxy , Samsung Galaxy Pro** in next activity list view.any know please help me.

Comment: Try this,
 
use `TextWatcher` it will help you.[Click here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-textwatcher-in-android

Comment: After i click the button in first activity,then it goes to 2nd activity and show **Samsung Galaxy , Samsung Galaxy Pro** list view in 2nd activity.

Comment: Hi yugesh i have posted sample code. please try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ways to do it, Here is one way ,you can create a custom method something like below.

```
 public ArrayList<String> getSearchedItems(String searchString){
 ArrayList<String>  list = new ArrayList<String>();

 for(int i = 0; i<array.length ;i++) { // array is the String array or list which contains all the Phone model names you want to search in.
  if((array[i].toLowerCase()).contains(searchString.toLowerCase())) { // contains method will check if user enterred string is available in your Model names
    list.add(array[i]);
    }
 }
 return list; // list of strings/names containing search String.
}
```

Call this method in your go button press, or from next Activity. to get list of names.

Comment: Contain not ignore the UPPERCASE OR LOWERCASE.we have to give the Name in upper case means upper case & lower case means lower case.other wise its not accept.

Comment: did not got you ? you can always have another if condition which will check upperCase as well something like, array[i].contains(stringSearch.toUpperCase()), make it as or condition in the loop

Comment: Like try make both Strings in lower case and check, I hope you want to give a result independent of case. Check my edited answer. Try some logics as par ur requirement too, We can not provide exact solutions, No?

Comment: for Example **Mac Mini** means if i give mini it was not search.If i give exact name Mini i will display Mac Mini.

Comment: as i said, why not to convert both the strings in a singleCase upper or lower doesnt matter right, and it will return true in any case.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

private EditText searchEdt;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // making it full screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ugsimply_beta);
    list.add("Samsung Tab");
    list.add("Samsung Note");
    list.add("Nokia Lumia");
    list.add("Nokia 5130");
    list.add("Sony Xperia");
    searchEdt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchEdt);
    searchEdt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        private int textlength;
        private ArrayList<String> arrayList_sort = new ArrayList<String>();

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            textlength = searchEdt.getText().length();
            if (arrayList_sort != null)
                arrayList_sort.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                if (textlength <= list.get(i).toString().length()) {

                    if (searchEdt
                            .getText()
                            .toString()
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                    (String) list.get(i).toString()
                                            .subSequence(0, textlength))) {
                        arrayList_sort.add(list.get(i));
                        Log.d("TAG", "log" + arrayList_sort.size());
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

You will get searched items `arrayList_sort`. Put this array list to another `Activity`

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class);

i.putStringArrayListExtra("arraylist", arrayList_sort);
startActivity(i);
```