# How to change what is written in one text field to another text in another TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I would like to check what letters are written in an EditText. This text should then be converted to some other text in another text field.

An example "word" = "yqtf" by moving the letters 2 times to the right in the alphabet.

Is there any way I could e.g. define the different letters in the text so that an "a" in the text becomes the number 1, "b" becomes 2 and so on as this would make it easier to mix the letters in different ways and then convert these numbers back into letters in another text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ASCII code of each character (which is an integer), add 2 to that code and then convert back to char. An array of characters can be obtained using [toCharArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29). You will have something like this:

```
String initialString = "yourString";
char[] chars = initialString.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i)
    chars[i] = (char)((int)chars[i] + 2);
String resultString = new String(chars);
```

Comment: thx for the answer but when i write that it still ask to initialize c. should i put "char c = 0;" in instead?

Comment: `char c` is every character in your input string. I've edited my code example.

Comment: the new editing makes much more sence :) i thought something was wrong with the for loop :P but could not see what xD

Answer (score 0):

To check live input chars in edittext, you should use `TextWatcher`, for more example please see this link [How to use the TextWatcher class in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-textwatcher-in-android)