# What is the best way to implement a large form layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

In my application I have to generate a big form with lot of elements (an element is usually and label + attribute (edditext, spinner, checkbox,...)).

When a form contains more elements (>20), the application is start lagging, opening the keyboard by example take around 1-2sec or the scrolling is slow.

**What I tried**

1. At the moment each element is inflated from xml (a LinearLayout with a TextView and another component) and added to form layout. I tried to "re-use" (practically re-add) an element but I got and exception saying that the View already has a parent which make sense since I was already added to my form layout.
2. I tried to add all the elements in a ListView to make sure that the views are re-used.
   It is working but not verry good: the problem in this case is that if I have an EditText, the user enter some text and scroll to bottom of the list, I couldn't find a way to save the text from EditText so I will be added back in EditText when the element will be visible again in ListView (the user scroll back to my element).

**Question**

Do you know any way to use lot of UI components but in same time to keep a good app performance? Do you think it is possible to get the text from an EditText just before the user start the scroll?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have some sort of preference screen. If that is the case, consider using [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html). If that will not work, what about a `ListView`, which has built-in methods for reusing layout? If neither of these options will work, you can create your own *ViewAdapter*, which works in very much the same way as a `ListView`. Simply create a class - such as `MyViewAdapter`. It should take in arguments to help configure what it will look like - such as the label text and what the other element is:

```
public class MyViewAdapter {

    public static enum InputType {
        editor, spinner, checkbox
    };

    private CharSequence labelText;
    private InputType input;

    public MyViewAdapter(CharSequence text, InputType inputType) {
        this.labelText = text;
        this.input = inputType;
    }

}
```

As for knowing what text is inside your `EditText` - just use [TextWatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-textwatcher-in-android) to listen for changes to the text. Although you can get before and after scroll callbacks, it requires hacking the built-in `ScrollView`. This example is added into the below code.

Next, add a method called `getView(Context)` as follows:

```
public View getView(Context context) {
    //here is where you inflate your view. For example:
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv.setText(labelText);
    ll.addView(tv);

    switch (input) {
        case (InputType.spinner) : {
            //TODO (see editor example)
            break;
        }
        case (InputType.checkbox) : {
            //TODO (see editor example)
            break;
        }
        default ://default to editor
        case (InputType.editor) : {
            EditText et = new EditText(context);
            et.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
            ll.addView(et);
            break;
        }
    }

    return ll;
}
```

Finally, to use this ViewAdapter, create them in your main activity:

```
List<MyViewAdapter> adapters = new ArrayList<MyViewAdapter>();//easy way to manage these.

//for each adapter, do something like:
adapters.add(new MyViewAdapter("myText:", InputType.editor));
```

Then, to inflate the views, do:

```
//Let's say your Main View is a LinearLayout called myView.
for (MyViewAdapter adapter : adapters) {
    myView.addView(adapter.getView(context));
}
```