# How does TextWatcher.onTextChanged() handle predictive text?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textwatcher

How are start, before, and count values called when we choose a prediction, for ex Do->Doc->Document. It sometimes deletes the word and inserts again with 2 calls, sometimes in the same call.

Please advice.

Comment: If you're trying to implement a TextView with autocomplete suggestions, use the AutocompleteTextView. More information can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-textwatcher-in-android) link & take reference. of below code.

```
 et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

          /*Whenever You will Enter Any Word, Here You will Predict that Which Character       is inserted.*/
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

**OR** 
As @Saket Suggested.
if you are using TextView for Text watching then use AutoCompleteTextView with below code.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> aCustListAdapterNo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            mContext, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,
            fillAutoCompleteCustomerListNo);
    **autoCompletetxtViewCUSListNo.setThreshold(1);**
    autoCompletetxtViewCUSListNo.setAdapter(aCustListAdapterNo);
```

Hope this helps you.