# Somthing like key listener for text field

Tags: android, textfield, textedit

I want to do something with a text field in my program that as soon as the user presses a key on keyborad and writes the first character of a word a special task begin executing something like click listener on a button but for a text field

I will be thankful if you help me

Comment: use textwatcher and run your task inside onTextChanged...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextView dont receive key pressed. You need an EditText to do this.

Follow the code below:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {          
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {                                   
   //here is your code
}                       
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
}                       
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) or [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)?

In case of EditText you can use a [TextWatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-textwatcher-in-android). Here you can use the method "onTextChanged".