# Android development - listen to textview events in the focused activity while not having access to the main code (SDK)

Tags: android, android-activity, textview

I'm developing an SDK for Android. The SDK should get text from any textview whose text is being set.

So I thought about listening to an activity change event (if there is any), then, listen to all the textview set events for the focused activity and by this get the text from the text view.

Is this possible?
Could you please lead me to an example?
I'm new to Android DEV (but not at all to DEV :)).

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you want to create an onTextChange listener in your sdk and allow the user of your sdk to register their editText when imlplimenting

Comment: Thanks.
This led me to investigate further and I've found that TextWatcher is needed for this task.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-textwatcher-in-android