# button with fill part and image part -android

Tags: android, view

[image]

I want to do something like the image.

This is an email fill button. when the user enter his email, the title "אימייל"("Email) should be disable ,so that use cannot touch it.

what is the way to do it?
thanks :)

Comment: Have you think is possible to do two difference things at same time like enter email and also touch title ?

Comment: please explain more about your question which views are you using ?? and did you try any ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#F2F2F2"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:text="Your mail" />

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:text="New Button" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="אימייל" />
```

The result is :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make one textwatcher for that edittext and if total Charactes are >0 then enable your button other wise

```
Yourbutton.setEnable(false)
```

Try that.
Here is the textwatcher example

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8543479/2931489

Comment: maybe you dont understand me? I dont want the edit text will fill also the "אימייל" text..

Comment: Sorry i can't understand you. Make it simpler and tell me what is this "אימייל