# android edittext input price format

Tags: android

I have a issue. My applications require formatting the EditText's value while typing. I.E., a number that needs to be formatted with decimal and thousands separators. Example, I input 123456789, this number must appear 123.456.789.

How to I do this issue ? Thank all.

Answer (score 0):

Нou can implement TextWatcher to your editText. Here're useful links for you:

[How to use the TextWatcher class in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-the-textwatcher-class-in-android)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

There you need to upgrade your number.
Or you can create your own customEditText.