# Call another Activity automatically when edit text data's enter

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to call another activity automatically without no event,

After i enter the data's in EditText Box to open the another activity in automatically

Answer (score 2):

You have to use TextWatcher. In textWatcher,

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
if (count > 0) {
// start your actvity in this
 } }
```

It works.

Answer (score 0):

No event?? That means it's random..

Do you mean that you want specific text entered into the `EditText`? Use a `TextWatcher` like here:

[How to use the TextWatcher class in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-the-textwatcher-class-in-android)

That will allow you to monitor the text and launch activities or whatever, based on the text input.

It won't tell you when someone is "done" or when it "should" launch. In other words, something has to happen - some event - even if it's the completion of a word, sentence, number, etc. Or even if someone starts typing and then stops...