# Is there anyway I could specify the height of the edit text in Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to know if there is any way I could customize the height of an edit text that I am using. I want it to be something similar to this picture [Comment Box](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e4qw5ms9a4ukugo/comment-box.png?dl=0)

This is my code so far;

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#ffe7e7e7"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

I would like to also know if I could notify the user how much character they have got left to write inside that edit text. So like 100 characters left out of 1000 characters. How can I go about doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define lines attribute

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lines="5"/>
```

To keep count, you can add TextWatcher to you EditText

Refer:
[How to use the TextWatcher class in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-the-textwatcher-class-in-android)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html