# How to store Android keyboard activity like any text type by other app and send it across Internet in background?

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-keypad

I would like to know how to store other application's keyboard activity  like capture passwords or userid as the user types and send it across Internet? Is there any mechanism built into Android that would do that?

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, how exactly do you intend to use this function? For what purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Another methods are also there to identify a user is typing 
For example if you implement TextWatcher you can get it the facility like when user type somethings you can call any webservice to get notified.

For TextWatcher follow the link :[How to use the TextWatcher class in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-the-textwatcher-class-in-android)

For Web Service implement your own or use third party.

Thanks hope this will help you.

Comment: no i just need to capture text that type by other application

Comment: That is malicious activity @SanjayBhalani .but I am working on it ,when I will get the solution i will inform you here thanks.

Comment: @sahu have you managed it?

Answer (score 1):

What you're referring to is known as a remote keylogger. It would be highly unlikely for Google, or the maintainers of Android operating systems to implement any malicious code into their work.

If you're referring to purchasing items from the App store and using them, then it's possible, but I have not heard of it. App store apps found to be malicious in nature would be quickly outed and their producer(s) would be outed.

Comment: no i just need to capture any application keyboard activity like some one try to type message on whats app i try to developed broadcast receiver but it work only if our app is open