# Android studio add text to edit text on key down

Tags: android

I have an EditText and where user is supposed to enter a time in format: `hh:mm`.
When the user has entered the hour I want to add a semicolon to the edit text automatically. I thought of something like an onKeyDown method that checks if the edit text consists of two numbers, in that case add a semicolon. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the TextWatcher class in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-the-textwatcher-class-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `TextWatcher` that does exactly what you need. Basically it has 3 methods: `beforeTextChanged()`, `onTextChanged()`, `afterTextChanged()`.

First two methods are not used to change text inside of EditText, they are just used to keep track of changes made on text. The **last one** is the method where we can modify and style text. The code will look something like this:

```
String text = "";

yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            // work with editable here and add :

            String newValue = editable.toString();

            if (newValue.length() > text.length()) {
                text = editable.toString();
                if (text.length() == 2) {
                    yourEditText.setText(text + ":");
                }
            }
            else if (newValue.length() < text.length()) {
                text = editable.toString();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This worked great. I have one problem tho, if have typed "13:30" and wants to delete it, when I delete the semicolon, it prints out the semicolon again because there are two number after the text changed.

I tried searching for this but couldn't find anything that worked, I want something like if(keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)

Comment: @SimonAndersson I have updated my answer. Take a carefull look at it

Answer (score 2):

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

@Override    
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count,int after) {
}

@Override    
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) {
  if(s.length() == 2)
   editText.setText(S+":");
  if(s.length() == 5) //(hh:mm) length is 5
   editText.setEnabled(false); //it accept only 5 char.
}
});
```