# EditText, how to hide DrawableRight

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-drawable

I want to have DrawableRight in my text area, but when i start typing then it should disappear. So i have code for EditText and function that knows when to hide drawable, but i don't know how to call that function. Can you help me?

```
//XML CODE
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/textt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:ems="10"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:hint="Wpisz wiadomość"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:maxLines="4" />

//JAVA CODE
public void camera(View v)
{
    EditText textArea=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.textt);
    if(textArea.getText()==null)
    {
        textArea.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_camera_alt_black_18dp), null);
    }
    else
        textArea.setCompoundDrawables(null,null,null,null);
}
```

SOLUTION:
I handled with it! First of all i changed "this" to "MainActivity.this". Second was very important - set bounds for drawable! Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to your Edittext.
Pls. see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-the-textwatcher-class-in-android).

In `onTextChanged` you can check - if `CharSequence s` length is > 0, then you have some text entered and should hide drawable.
`CharSequence s` is a param that you receive in `onTextChanged` method.

Comment: Almost done. Now i have problem with argument "this"  in this code                 textArea.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_camera_alt_black_18dp), null);
: Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'android.text.TextWatcher', required: 'android.content.Context'

Comment: If this code is inside your activity (`MainActivity`, for example), place `MainActivity.this` instead of `this`. If it's inside a fragment, put `getActivity()`. This is happening because your code now is inside `TextWatcher`, so `this` points to `TextWatcher` now.

Answer (score 0):

For hide textArea's drabwable, you might try this:

```
Drawable[] drawables = textArea.getCompoundDrawables();
for (Drawable d: drawables) {
    if (d != null) {
        d.setAlpha(0);
    }
}
```