# Disable a button

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello I would like to do this : I have two EditText and one button and I would like to disable the button if one of the EditText is empty. To do this I try this :

```
if(editText1!!.getText().length  == 0 || editText2!!.getText().length  == 0 ){
            button1!!.setEnabled(false)
        }
```

The problem is my button is everytime disable... and I would when the two EditText are not empty I can click on the button...

How can I do this ?

Thank you !

Comment: Use textwatcher -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-the-textwatcher-class-in-android

Comment: Thank you indeed I think I have to use textwatcher but the problem is I have two editText...

Comment: Check now. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited : after clarification from OP.
If you want to check two editTexts , you can do something like following,

```
        boolean editText1Empty = true;
        boolean editText2Empty = true;

        editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                editText1Empty = charSequence.length() == 0;
                checkButton();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        editText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                editText2Empty = charSequence.length() == 0;
                checkButton();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        void checkButton() {
        button.setEnable(!editText1Empty && !editText2Empty);
        }
```

Comment: You could just write the condition as the parameter for `setEnabled`

Comment: That's cleaver :)  But I think this will give OP more clarity.

Comment: I will make it one `TextWatcher` only and check for both `EditText.isEmpty()` on that `onTextChanged()`. I think it will be more pure.