# Is it possible to autofill an EditText in an application without clicking any buttons?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, autofill

I have this form for the user to fill up and one of the Edit Text is BMI and I was thinking if it is possible to auto fill that BMI Edit Text after the user has enter the Height and Weight without clicking any button. I have Googled and found such thing called Text Watcher. I tried implementing it in my code but when I run the application the Edit Text for the BMI is still empty and so is the database.

```
package mdad.project;

import com.example.manandhowproject.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Userreg extends Activity implements TextWatcher {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Button btnNext;
    EditText etName, etAge, etHeight, etWeight, etBMI;
    double result;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.userreg);
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        etHeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etHeight);
        etWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWeight);
        etBMI = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBMI);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignOut);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View V) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Log Out Success ! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent msg2 = new Intent(Userreg.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(msg2);
            }
        });

        Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View V) {
                String name = etName.getText().toString();
                String age = etAge.getText().toString();
                int nAge = new Integer(age).intValue();
                String height = etHeight.getText().toString();
                int nHeight = new Integer(height).intValue();
                String weight = etWeight.getText().toString();
                int nWeight = new Integer(weight).intValue();
                String bmi = etBMI.getText().toString();
                String sql = "insert into UserInfo (Name,Age,Height,Weight,BMI) values( '" + name + "','" + nAge + "','" + nHeight + "', '" + nWeight + "', '" + bmi + "')";
                String result = updateTable(sql);

                Intent msg3 = new Intent(Userreg.this, Regsuccess.class);
                startActivity(msg3);
            }
        });
        String sql = "create table if not exists UserInfo (recld integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, Name text, Age text, Height text, Weight text, BMI text )";
        String result = createDatabase(sql, "UserInf.db");
    }

    private void calculate() {

        String height = etHeight.getText().toString();
        int nHeight = new Integer(height).intValue();
        String weight = etWeight.getText().toString();
        int nWeight = new Integer(weight).intValue();
        result = nWeight / (nHeight * nHeight);
        String textResult = "" + result;
        etBMI.setText(textResult);

    }


    String createDatabase(String sql, String dbName) {
        try {
            System.out.println(sql);
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("sdcard/" + dbName, null);
            db.beginTransaction();
            db.execSQL(sql);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            db.endTransaction();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            return ("error open DB");
        }

        return "";
    }

    String updateTable(String sql) {
        try {
            System.out.println(sql);
            db.beginTransaction();
            db.execSQL(sql);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            db.endTransaction();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            return ("Error updating DB");
        }
        return ("DB updated");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        calculate();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-the-textwatcher-class-in-android) result...

Comment: The question was not about how to use `TextWatcher` but was more specific, as it contained other bugs as well that caused the user's code not to work as intended.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are missing

```
etHeight.addTextChangedListener(this);
etWeight.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

in `onCreate()`.

Also, update your `calculate()` method as it contains a bug on the calculation of BMI:

```
private void calculate() {

    try {
        String height = etHeight.getText().toString();
        int nHeight = Integer.parseInt(height);
        String weight = etWeight.getText().toString();
        int nWeight = Integer.parseInt(weight);
        result = nWeight / (nHeight * nHeight);
        String textResult = "" + result;
        etBMI.setText(textResult);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        etBMI.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I have added the 2 lines of statement as you advised but now whenever I tried to key in any number  on height or weight, the whole app will crash. But it does not crash when I enter alphabets. (I think this is because I set the edittext input value to number only) So can you further advise? Thanks

Comment: It's because you do not validate the inputs in your `calculate()` method. When the text is invalid, an exception is thrown (which causes the crash). I have updated my answer, check it out. It might need some adjustments, as I haven't run the code. Finally, please accept the answer if it has helped you :)

Comment: Hi, thanks alot for your advise. Currently I am able to get the autofill working however the value it keeps autofilling is 0 no matter what. Can you please further advise? I'd really appreciate your help

Comment: Okay, there's another bug. `result` is `double`, but the expression `nWeight / (nHeight * nHeight)` (in `calculate()`) yields an `int`, which causes the result to be 0. Change it to `(double) nWeight / (nHeight * nHeight)`.

Comment: Alright so I managed to get it working, thanks alot !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways,

**FIRST** by using `TextWatcher` as everyone is giving solution. And,

**SECOND** way is, by using `OnFocusChangeListener` for EditText. Here's the example how you can achieve it,

```
EditText one = findViewById(R.id.one);
EditText two = findViewById(R.id.two);
EditText three = findViewById(R.id.three);

three.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus){
                Double ONE = Double.parseDouble(one.getText().toString().trim());
                Double TWO = Double.parseDouble(two.getText().toString().trim());
                Double THREE = ONE+TWO;
                three.setText(String.valueOf(THREE));
                Log.i("tag", "onFocusChange: "+THREE);
                //or you can perform any other task
            }
        }
});
```

As shown in above example, as user set focus on `third` EditText, it takes the value from `first` and `second` EditText and shows the result.