# How to check and validate , given editext is phone number or mobile number?

Tags: android, validation

In my app login using mobile number or phone number in single edittext.
if we give digits it check valid phone number else if we give character(alphabet) check it is valid email address.

Note : check both email and phone number in single edit text.

Here java code,

```
if (username.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                erroredit(username, getResources().getString(R.string.login_label_alert_username));
            } else if (!isValidEmail(username.getText().toString().replace(" ","").trim())) {
                erroredit(username, getResources().getString(R.string.login_label_alert_email_invalid));
            } else if (!isValidmobilenumber(username.getText().toString().replace(" ","").trim())) {
                erroredit(username, getResources().getString(R.string.register_label_alert_phoneNo));
            }
            else if (password.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                erroredit(password, getResources().getString(R.string.login_label_alert_password));
            }
```

Attached screenshot here,

[image]

Comment: In If statement check  that text is Email Id in else if statement check it's a phone number or not use else based on your needs that's enough

Comment: i need to check some condition 1) if user give character means, we check its valid email address or not? 2) if user give number means, we check length greater 6 or not? . so first we need to check whether given string is number or alphabet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String data = editemail.getText().toString().trim();
            String pass = edtPass.getText().toString().trim();

            boolean flag = false;

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {
                edtPass.setError("Enter password");
                //edtPass.requestFocus();
            }else {

            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(data)) {
                editemail.setError("Enter Data");
            } else {
                if (data.matches("[0-9]+")) {
                    if (data.length() < 10 && data.length() > 10) {
                        editemail.setError("Please Enter valid phone number");
                        editemail.requestFocus();
                    } else {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(data).matches()) {
                        editemail.setError("Please Enter valid email");
                        editemail.requestFocus();
                    }else {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)&&flag){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: if (data.length() < 10 && data.length() > 10) you can change it with false xD

Answer (score 2):

you can combine codes to achieve that, first add the following methods:

```
private boolean isValidMobile(String phone) {
    boolean check=false;
    if(!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", phone)) {
        if(phone.length() < 6 || phone.length() > 13) {
        // if(phone.length() != 10) { 
            check = false;
            txtPhone.setError("Not Valid Number");
        } else {
            check = true;
        }
    } else {
        check=false;
    }
    return check;
}
```

and for email validatio add this one:

```
private boolean isValidMail(String email) {
    boolean check;
    Pattern p;
    Matcher m;

    String EMAIL_STRING = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    p = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_STRING);

    m = p.matcher(email);
    check = m.matches();

    if(!check) {
        txtEmail.setError("Not Valid Email");
    }
    return check;
}
```

also this is needed to check if the string numeric or not

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
{
  return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");  //match a number with optional '-' and decimal.
}
```

in your code you call those function like

```
if(isValidMobile(login) || isValidMail(login){
    // success
    if(isNumeric(login)){
        //it mean the user typed a phone number
        //show phone invalid image
    }
    else{
        //show email invalid image
    }
}
else { 
     // failure 
}
```

Comment: i need to check some condition                  1) if user give character means, we check its valid email address or not?   2) if user give number means, we check length greater 6 or not? . so first we need to check whether given string is number or alphabet

Comment: What are the conditions, state your goal so we can help you

Comment: i have changed my answer, the method IsValidMobile and IsValidEmail will help you to check the validation of the value entered by the user either way (no need to check the lenght or not), if one of the test is validated you will check if it's numeric or not in order to show the specific image you want

Answer (score 1):

assume your `EditText` variable is `editText`:

```
String username = editText.getText().toString();
if(android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(username).matches() 
 ||
 android.util.Patterns.PHONE.matcher(username).matches()){
   //do stuff
}
else{
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: i need to check some condition 1) if user give character means, we check its valid email address or not? 2) if user give number means, we check length greater 6 or not? . so first we need to check whether given string is number or alphabet

Comment: this builtin Patterns would check what you want.

Answer (score 0):

[I very often use this dependency when it comes to manipulating phone numbers. It's very useful.](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject)

For email it's not complicated just check the character "@" and "."

Comment: i need to check some condition 1) if user give character means, we check its valid email address or not? 2) if user give number means, we check length greater 6 or not? . so first we need to check whether given string is number or alphabet

Answer (score 0):

If you want real time checking while user is writing then you can have a TextWatcher  [How to use the TextWatcher class in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-the-textwatcher-class-in-android)

Do your checks in the afterTextChanged override method with `android.util.Patterns.PHONE` or an equivalent like the user Godot explained above.