# How to implement filer (search) in a heterogeneous recyclerview with two different viewholders?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CilV5.png) I am not able to implement search in **heterogeneous recyclerview** with two different viewholders. Can anyone suggest me something. Moreover my views of recyclerview are textViews and cardViews. CardView is having data written on it for example name, age and phone number. I want to search with the name and phone number. Nothing with the date textView.

[See publishResults image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwEXn.png)

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code :

```
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                // Search is empty/Nothing Entered
                mAppointmentsList = mAppointmentsListFiltered;
            } else {
                List<DataAppointments> filterResults = new ArrayList<>();

                for (DataAppointments data : mAppointmentsList) {
                    if (data instanceof DataPatientDetails) {
                        DataPatientDetails details = (DataPatientDetails) data;

                        if (details.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) ||
                                details.getPhone().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) ||
                                details.getId().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                            filterResults.add(data);

                            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                                Log.d(TAG, "performFiltering: " + details.getName());
                        }
                    }
                }

                mAppointmentsListFiltered = filterResults;
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "performFilteringPatientListFiltered: " + mAppointmentsListFiltered);
            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = mAppointmentsListFiltered;
            results.count = mAppointmentsListFiltered.size();
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                Log.d(TAG, "performFilteringResultsUpcoming: " + results.count);
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mAppointmentsListFiltered = (ArrayList<DataAppointments>) results.values;
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "publishResults: " + mAppointmentsListFiltered);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}`
```

And my onQueryChangeListener :

```
    // Query Search in Material Search view
private void querySearch() {
    if (getActivity() != null)
        mSearchView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_view_upcoming);
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextSubmit: " + query);
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextChange: " + newText);
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextChange: " + mAdapter.getItemCount());

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Implementing search should be view agnostic. Apply the filter on your data list. Post the code if you can.

Comment: @RickSanchez i want to filter on the basis of data related to one type of view that is cardView only. Moreover they both have different dataModels and so is their getters and setters. So for comparison in Filter() i am not getting how to compare them. Because i am using a list (parent dataModel type, that has both kinds of dataModels).

Comment: I am posting the image of the code. The comparison part will come at "//.." part in the image.

Comment: mAppoiuntmentList is of type DataAppointments model (parent), and have two types of children dataModels DataPatientDetails and DataDate. But function getName() and getPhone() are in DataPatientDetails. So how can i do the comparison? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use `instanceof` keyword to check if model is of type `DataPatientDetails`. Then cast it and compare name or phone_no against the search string.

Comment: If you can help me in code it would be appreciated.@RickSanchez :)

Comment: Please copy the code in the question, it's will be easier that way. Thanks.

Comment: Have pasted the code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you posted.

in the else statement, I am not exactly sure what is being compared. You can have condition to check if `DataAppointments` is of type `DataPatientDetails` and then do your comparision. I am assuming `mAppointmentsList` is an actual list of data.

```
else {
 for (DataAppointments data : mAppointmentsList) {
  if (data instanceof DataPatientDetails) {
    DataPatientDetails details = (DataPatientDetails) data;
    // do your comparision here, if it passes, then add to the filtered results
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me where i am getting it wrong. I think its in `publishResults` function. I am posting image at the end of my asked question.

Comment: Are you getting the proper values in the logs for the filtered data? and are you using `mAppointmentsListFiltered` as your actual dataset in the `recyclerView`?

Comment: yes i am getting right values in the log for filtered results. But it do not filter simultaneously when we type. but when i click back button of phone it gives me the result. After which whole Adapter is cleared don't know how and have to create activity again to fetch data again.

Comment: This is the link of the video what my problem actually is. [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ehuhV6NVTNUp9wlPtslJ8GtHr_WGZ6Cd)

Comment: You will need to implement `TextWatcher` to achieve live update as you type. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-the-textwatcher-class-in-android

Comment: I am using onQueryChange listener. code i am posting in the question. Please see it also.

Comment: Moreover the same code works fine with homogeneous recylerView.

Comment: And also .addTextChange listener cannot to applied to material Search view i am using. @Rick

Comment: Try to debug using a breakpoint, to check if on every letter typed, `onQueryChange` listener is called and eventually the filter method.

Comment: Here is the log ` performFilteringPatientListFiltered: [com.rethinkux.myappointments.data.DataPatientDetails@8b8c547]
    performFilteringResultsUpcoming: 1
06-29 13:13:13.683 26113-27203/com.rethinkux.myappointments D/UpcomingAppointmentsRvAdapter: Filter Called 
06-29 13:13:13.735 26113-27204/com.rethinkux.myappointments D/UpcomingAppointmentsRvAdapter: Filter Called 
    performFiltering: Mohit Nagpal
06-29 13:13:13.792 26113-27206/com.rethinkux.myappointments D/UpcomingAppointmentsRvAdapter: Filter Called 
    performFilteringResultsUpcoming: 3`

Comment: It is called on every char i enter.

Comment: but i noticed one thing that my Apadpter items are not changing they are remaining constant and are not updating. @Rick can you tell me why?

Comment: is this not your adapter list items `mAppointmentsListFiltered`?

Comment: It is. but i don't know why its not updating.

Comment: Check once what is being passed in `publishResults` method. Because that's where `mAppointmentsListFiltered` is being updated. And make sure no where else `mAppointmentsListFiltered' is getting updated.

Comment: seen it. The same thing works fine in other fragment with homogeneous items.

Comment: `mAdapter.getItemCount` always gives us total number of items not filtered in both `onQueryTextSubmit` and `onQueryTextChange`.

Comment: I figured out in my code when search view is empty, it should be `mAppointmentsListFiltered = mAppointmentList`. After correcting it i got that my Adapter isn't getting updated and search isn't working in both functions either.

Comment: Problem solved. :) I was returning orignal list always in Adapter's `getItemCount` now when i returned `mAppointmentsFilteredList` it works fine now. Thanks by the way for your response :)

Comment: Doesn't this answer solves your first problem related to filtering data of 2 different modals? If it does, please mark this as correct answer. Always happy to help :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Search is not depends upon view, it is depend upon data. Apply filer upon your list according to your criteria and differentiate your view with viewType.