# Confuse with simple condition

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I don't know why I confuse with simple if/ else condition? In my app, phone verification part, Bydefault I set sendVerification button disable, and when I enter text then it should enable. but it is not enabling? What is wrong with my condition? even if I try with else part, same problem!

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PhoneAuthActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/PhoneToolbar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar">
    </include>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/DialLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/PhoneToolbar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dial"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dial"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/PhoneNumber"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Phone Number"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="phone"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/PhoneProgress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LockLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/DialLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lock"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/lock"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/code"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Verification Code"
            android:layout_weight="8"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/CodeProgress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/VerificationText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="91dp"
        android:text="A verification code will be sent to your phone number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendVerification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FF0000"
        android:text="Send Verification" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**And this is Activity**

```
package com.jimmytrivedi.lapitchat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class PhoneAuthActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout DialLayout, LockLayout;
    private EditText PhoneNumber, code;
    private ProgressBar PhoneProgress, CodeProgress;
    private Button sendVerification;
    private Toolbar PhoneToolbar;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private String number;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_auth);

        DialLayout = findViewById(R.id.DialLayout);
        LockLayout = findViewById(R.id.LockLayout);
        PhoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.PhoneNumber);
        code = findViewById(R.id.code);
        PhoneProgress = findViewById(R.id.PhoneProgress);
        CodeProgress = findViewById(R.id.CodeProgress);
        sendVerification = findViewById(R.id.sendVerification);
        PhoneToolbar = findViewById(R.id.PhoneToolbar);

        PhoneProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        CodeProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        sendVerification.setEnabled(false);

        setSupportActionBar(PhoneToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Welcome to Phone Verification");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        number = PhoneNumber.getText().toString();
        if (!number.isEmpty()) {
            sendVerification.setEnabled(true);
        }

        sendVerification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                PhoneNumber.setEnabled(false);
                PhoneProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                        number,
                        60,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                        PhoneAuthActivity.this,
                        mCallbacks
                );
            }
        });


        mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: You are currently setting the property "enabled" to false at creation time. I think you are missing an event listener on the input where you can type your data (phonenumber), which will enable your button based on your condition.

Comment: I'm not getting OTP after applied TextWatcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```
number = PhoneNumber.getText().toString();
    if (!number.isEmpty()) {
        sendVerification.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

is  executed only once at onCreate. You'll have to add a text change listener and enable/disable the button accordingly
like,

```
PhoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
 @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

 @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
   int count, int after) {
 }

 @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
  int before, int count) {
  if(s.length() > 0)
  {
    sendVerification.setEnabled(true);
  }
```

}
});

Comment: I'm not getting OTP after applied TextWatcher.

Comment: What do you mean ? Can you give us more details please?

Comment: it is going in : public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

Comment: Not getting OTP

Comment: Can you please move you line
      number = PhoneNumber.getText().toString(); to sendVerification onClickListener ?

Comment: Cool. Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

```
number = PhoneNumber.getText().toString();
if (!number.isEmpty()) {
    sendVerification.setEnabled(true);
}
```

This is all executed in onCreate before you get the chance to start typing. Once you start typing this code is not executed again. It is only executed once, when the activity is being created.

Solution: set up a TextWatcher on the phone number editText and enable/disable sendVerification in the TextWatcher#afterTextChanged method. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-the-textwatcher-class-in-android) for instructions on how to do it.

Comment: Please send me the exac code, I don't aware about Textwatcher

Comment: make yourself aware. I'm not going to spoonfeed you the code. Just follow the link

Comment: I'm not getting OTP after applied TextWatcher.

Comment: @PalakSingh that is a different problem. Make a new question for that

Answer (score 0):

You need a TextWatcher to do what you wish to do, so add a TextWatcher to your EditText/TextView like below:

```
PhoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    if (s.length()>0) {
                        sendVerification.setEnabled(true);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
```

The reason your code wasn't working is because the onCreate() method does not get called after you start typing, meaning the  condition for enabling your view is checked only once so any changes are not checked again.

Comment: I'm not getting OTP after applied TextWatcher.