# How to understand stop and start typing like whatsapp for EditText?

Tags: android, timer, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have edittext and I want to understand stop and start typing. I listened textwatcher onTextChanged and I use timer for typing.

But when edittext's text is not empty, I don't understand correctly actual typing operation.

I want to see:

> My edittext text:
>
> --ad-- --> typing...
>
> --ads-- --> typing...
>
> --ads-- --> after 900 ms stop typing .  ::: but not understand

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, final int before, final int count) {

            if (count != 0 && count >= before) {
                typingTimer.startTyping();
                return;
            }

            typingTimer.stopTyping();

        }
    };
```

Comment: I think this post will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-the-textwatcher-class-in-android

Comment: Thank you for posting. No I know already textwatcher but I don't trace typing like whatsapp

Comment: ok, thanks for edited question. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a timer in fact.

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private final long TYPING_DELAY = 900; // milliseconds

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, final int before, final int count) {

        // do what you want
        // show "is typing"

        timer.cancel();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(
            new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // here, you're not typing anymore
                }
            }, 
            TYPING_DELAY
        );

    }
};
```