# create tags with bubble when user click on space button

Tags: java, android

[image]

I want to create a tag when the user clicks on the space button after writing some text.

I have mentioned an image of my desire output

Comment: take a look at chips item in new material design at this tutorial https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/chips-material-components-for-android-46001664a40f

Comment: I want to create  tags when user  press space button without using any hint  or already data inserted list

Comment: You can use chips library for showing tags and using a textWatcher on a edittext for input text, after user type a "space" char, you need to create a new chip for your tag. (save your tags in a arraylist in that textwatcher method) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-the-textwatcher-class-in-android

Answer (score 1):

check [this](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete) library.

Just see the example project to learn how to use it.
use `setTokenizer()` to add `space` as token like this :

`setTokenizer(new CharacterTokenizer(Arrays.asList(',', ';',' '), " "));`

in `CharacterTokenizer` constructor first parameter is list of character for splitting tags and second parameter is for when user hit spacial key to determine a new tag.