# onStop for Fragment in TabLayout to save some content

Tags: java, android

I have a TabLayout with two Tabs or Fragments.

In one Fragment I want to save for example text from edittext before switching tab or closing app.

I tried with onStop. It save the content before closing app. But when I go to second tab, the app closes without exception.

Why? Are the a solution for this problem?

Comment: If you want to save text from `EditText`, you can use `TextWatcher` class. Check this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-the-textwatcher-class-in-android

Comment: I would have to see the exception to tell you.