# How to do this in android OnKeyPress Logic

Tags: android

I have two `edittext`'s amount and percentage. When I type amount in `edittext` percentage `edittext` should change and vice versa. How to achieve this?

Comment: You use a TextWatcher on both edit texts.  You'll need to code carefully to avoid infinite looping the two though.

Comment: @GabeSechan any examples. does this work [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117209/how-to-know-key-presses-in-edittext]

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

**This is how you can achieve it.**

```
EditText percentage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.percentage);
EditText amount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.amount);
amount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // calculate percentage and set it to percentage here
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    } 
});
```

Comment: In that case only one `edittext` will work other will not work. try it you want