# Advanced recyclerview adapters

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have been trying to find information about creating advanced RecyclerView adapters.

I need two versions of adapters for my application.

1. The first one is similar to the [Google Keep](https://keep.google.com/) checklist. When you are adding a new item to the list, it adds a new cell at the end of the list.

ex: create a product list or wishlist.

I can already create an adapter with a multiple ViewTypes, but I can't find a solution to my problem (adding a new cell when adding a new item to the list)

2. second one is I need to have a list with multiple types of layouts. ex: Notes, Birthdays, Important, etc. with I separators in between them. 
   And when I delete all Birthdays from the list. How can I delete Birthday separator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question:

**Adding new cell at the bottom of the list when adding an new item**

[Setup listener on a view on item layout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMjI7cLsyfw&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuBtTYUuc5Pyo4V7xZ2HNtf4&index=6&t=0s) and add new item to the end of the list

ex: For Google Keep example implement code to add new item to the end of the list inside [edittext view `TextChangeListener`'s onTextChanged method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14251047/7356355) on the item layout.

```
inner class TaskViewHolder(mView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(mView) {

        val etTask: EditText = view.findViewById(R.id.et_task)

        init {
            etTask.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                }

                override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                }

                override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                    // add new item to the end of the list here

                }

            })
        }
    }
```

**Removing the separator when all the items in a group was deleted**

You could check to see if the list items in the group is empty and set the visibility of the separator to `GONE`

ex:

```
// here birthdays is ArrayList<Birthday>
if(birthdays.isEmpty()){
     separator.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try. Seems it can really help me

Comment: my pleasure. You may also try [epoxy](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy) or [fastadapter](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter)